# Merge Sort according to a key

Tags: c

In this program, it acts like a book store, that have information of price, relevance, star and ID, 
The program will need to sort the list according to price(from lowest to highest). The program only need to implement a merge sort(The sort will take a parameter of compare_on_price, so it will list the price from lowest to highest), and then Interface calls the sort at Interface function, lastly, in the main function it calls the interface.

The list of items are like this

```
Stars   Price   Relv    ID
4.5     12.49   7.9      1
5        7.99   7.6      2
2       16.99   6.2      3
2.5     15.49   9.1      4
3.5     20.99   6        5
1        9.99   8        6
1.5     13.99   1        7
5        8.49   8.3      8
3.5     10.49   5.2      9
```

After sorting, the price should list from lowest to highest. 
Errors so far: 
`part1.c:117:20: error: expected expression before ',' token`
`part1.c:117:20: warning: passing argument 1 of 'mergesort' makes pointer from integer without a cast`
`part1.c:74:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'`
`part1.c:117:20: warning: passing argument 4 of 'mergesort' makes pointer from integer without a cast`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

FILE *fp;

typedef struct book{
  double rating;
  double price;
  double relevance;
  int ID;
}B;

B *list;

int read_file(char* infile, int N)
{
  int c;
  if((fp=fopen(infile, "rb")))
    {
      fscanf(fp, "%*s\t%*s\t%*s\t%*s\n");
      c=0;
      while((!feof(fp))&&(c<N))
{
  fscanf(fp, "%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%d\n", &list[c].rating,  &list[c].price, &list[c].relevance, &list[c].ID);   
  c++;
}
  fclose(fp);      
}
  else
{
  fprintf(stderr,"%s did not open. Exiting.\n",infile);
  exit(-1);
}
  return(c);
}

int comp_on_rating(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  if ((*(B *)a).rating < (*(B *)b).rating)
    return -1;
  else if ((*(B *)a).rating > (*(B *)b).rating)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;  
}

int comp_on_relev(const void *a, const void *b)
{

  if ((*(B *)a).relevance < (*(B *)b).relevance)
    return -1;
  else if ((*(B *)a).relevance > (*(B *)b).relevance)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;  
}

int comp_on_price(const void *a, const void *b)
{

  if ((*(B *)a).price < (*(B *)b).price)
    return 1;
  else if ((*(B *)a).price > (*(B *)b).price)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;  
}


/* Stable sorting method: if it keeps elements with equal keys in he smae
relative order as they were in te input. */
void mergesort(int a[],int low, int high, int(*compar)(const void *, const void *))  
{  

 int i = 0;
 int length = high - low + 1;
 int pivot  = 0;
 int merge1 = 0;
 int merge2 = 0;
 int working[length];

 if(low == high)
  return;

 pivot  = (low + high) / 2;

 mergesort(a, low, pivot,compar );
 mergesort(a, pivot + 1, high,compar);

 for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
  working[i] = a[low + i];

 merge1 = 0;
 merge2 = pivot - low + 1;

 for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  if(merge2 <= high - low)
   if(merge1 <= pivot - low)
    if(working[merge1] > working[merge2])
     a[i + low] = working[merge2++];
    else
     a[i + low] = working[merge1++];
   else
    a[i + low] = working[merge2++];
  else
   a[i + low] = working[merge1++];
 }

} //end function.  

void user_interface(int N)
{

  // For Part 1 this function calls the sort function to sort on Price only
 mergesort(N,0,,N-1, comp_on_price);


}

void print_results(int N)
{
  int i;
  if((fp=fopen("top20.txt","w")))
    {
  for(i=N-1;i>=N-20;i--)
{

  printf("%g %g %g %d\n", list[i].rating, list[i].price, list[i].relevance, list[i].ID);
  fprintf(fp, "%g %g %g %d\n", list[i].rating, list[i].price, list[i].relevance, list[i].ID);

}
  fclose(fp);
    }
  else
    {
  fprintf(stderr,"Trouble opening output file top20.txt\n");
  exit(-1);
}

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int N;

  if(argc!=3)
    {
  fprintf(stderr, "./exec <input_size> <filename>\n");
  exit(-1);
}

  /* top 20 for example */
  N=atoi(argv[1]);

  list = (B *)malloc(N*sizeof(B));

  /*read the file into the n variable*/
  N=read_file(argv[2], N);

  user_interface(N);

  print_results(N);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Did you attempt to understand and fix the errors? In particular, if you had actually looked at line 117, you might have noticed that your call to mergesort is incorrect - you appear to be missing the first parameter, and have an extra comma. (An error message including part1.c:117:20 means that the error occurred in file part1.c, line 117, column 20.)

Comment: @Editors I removed the homework tag. Please see [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147527/166749).

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
mergesort(N,0,,N-1, comp_on_price);
            ^
          Extra , in there...
```

1. void mergesort(int a[],int low, int high, int(*compar)(const void *, const void *)) 
                   ^         ^        ^             ^
                array        int      int          function pointer

Your call:

```
 mergesort(N,0,,N-1, comp_on_price);
           ^ ^   ^         ^
          int int int     function name, 
                           a function point is an address of your function
```